# No matching bean of type path.repositoryClass found for dependency expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, jpa

I am new to Spring, and have searched extensively to resolve this problem, but no success yet.
 Under src/WEB-INF folder I have two files:

```
1. dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml
2. web.xml
```

Under src/META-INF, I have below files:

```
1. applicationContext.xml 
2. hibernate-context.xml 
3. orm.xml
4. persistence.xml 
5. spring-data.xml 
6. spring.properties
```

Source code for all is listed after the question in the sequence given above.
 I am not getting the error message (which is mentioned in subject) when I am removing the below line from dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.controller"/>
```

**But then it’s not creating the tables in DB.**

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.controller"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp"/>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp">
 <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>   

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
     <array>
       <bean id="jsonConverter"
          class="com.myapp.util.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
         <property name="objectMapper">
           <bean class="com.myapp.util.HibernateAwareObjectMapper"/>
         </property>
       </bean>
     </array>
    </property>
```

```
<!-- Imports datasource configuration -->
<import resource="spring-data.xml"/>

<bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
p:location="/META-INF/spring.properties" />
```

hibernate-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        ">

<context:property-placeholder location="/META-INF/spring.properties" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.myapp.repository" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
            p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
            p:acquireIncrement="5"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="100"
            p:maxStatements="50"
            p:minPoolSize="10" />

</beans>
```

orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-defaults>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <!--mapping-file>./META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file-->
            <class>com.myapp.model.ACLEntityManager</class>
            <class>com.myapp.model.MerchantACL</class>
            <class>com.myapp.model.Resource</class>
            <class>com.myapp.model.AdminACL</class>
            <class>com.myapp.model.Aggregator</class>
            <class>com.myapp.model.Customer</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>
    <mapping-file>./META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
</persistence-unit>
```

spring-data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

<!-- Activate Spring Data JPA repository support -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.myapp.repository" />

<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
<bean id="jpaDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
    p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
    p:acquireIncrement="5"
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
    p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxStatements="50"
    p:minPoolSize="10" />

<!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
            p:persistenceXmlLocation="./META-INF/persistence.xml"
    p:persistenceUnitName="hibernatePersistenceUnit"
    p:dataSource-ref="jpaDataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateVendor"/>

<!-- Specify our ORM vendor -->
<bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            p:showSql="true"/>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" 
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
```

spring.properties

```
# database properties
app.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
app.jdbc.username=root
app.jdbc.password=
```

Stack Trace:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminACLController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.service.AdminACLService com.myapp.controller.AdminACLController.adminACLService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminACLService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.myapp.repository.AdminACLRepository com.myapp.service.AdminACLService.adminACLRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.myapp.repository.AdminACLRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3920)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: @Robert Harvey, why do you think that the question is not clear?

Comment: My instinct is to close it as "wall of code," but your question is specific enough, and you've pointed out the line of code that is causing the trouble, so I'll leave it open.  We'll see if someone knows the answer.

Comment: Thanks for reopening it. Yeah, I agree with you that it's a wall of code. But trust me: for a newbie, java-spring-jpa-hibernate setup looks like that only.

Comment: Instead of putting all your config files, the stacktrace with the error would help.  The No matching bean of type path.repositoryClass look like a property name that is not translated to a class name!

Comment: also class AdminACLRepository is getting generated during compilation.

Comment: Altough it is already a lot of code, would you please list `com.myapp.controller.AdminACLController` and `com.myapp.service.AdminACLService`?

Comment: @skirsch I have posted both the files below (as an answer, because maximum word count already reached for the question).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that com.myapp.service.AdminACLService does not have an @Service annotation on it. If you do have that @Service annotation on that class you also need to make sure that you are scanning this package.

Not sure why you are doing this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp">
 <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Though I am not sure if that is a problem

Comment: AdminACLService already have /@Service annotation. I have also tried /@component, but not luck.  "If you do have that @Service annotation on that class you also need to make sure that you are scanning this package.": I could not get this point. Where should I make sure that I am scanning this package? (All the config files are already in the post)

Comment: I think the scanning is fine; the exclude makes sense, as the controllers only need to be defined in the `DispatcherServlet`'s application context, not within the root AC.

Answer (score 0):

AdminACLController

```
package com.myapp.controller;

import com.myapp.dto.AdminACLDTO;
import com.myapp.exception.NotFoundException;
import com.myapp.model.AdminACL;
import com.myapp.service.AdminACLService;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
public class AdminACLController {
@Autowired
private AdminACLService adminACLService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/adminACL", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody
AdminACLDTO add(
        // @RequestParam(value = "sessionUserId") String sessionUserId,

        //private Integer ;
//private String adminName;
        @RequestParam(value = "adminId") String adminId,
        @RequestParam(value = "adminName") String adminName
        ) 
        throws NotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {


    AdminACL checkAdminACL = this.adminACLService.getAdminACL(adminId);

    if (checkAdminACL == null) {
        AdminACL adminACL = new AdminACL();
        adminACL.setAdminId(Integer.parseInt(adminId));
        adminACL.setName(adminName);

        this.adminACLService.addAdminACL(adminACL);
        AdminACLDTO adminACLDTO = new AdminACLDTO(adminACL);
        return adminACLDTO;

    }
    throw new NotFoundException("Resource already added");
}
}
```

AdminACLService

```
package com.myapp.service;

import com.myapp.model.AdminACL;
import com.myapp.repository.AdminACLRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class AdminACLService {
@Autowired
AdminACLRepository adminACLRepository;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MerchantACLService.class);

@Transactional
public AdminACL addAdminACL(AdminACL admin) {
     adminACLRepository.save(admin);      
     return admin;   
   }

@Transactional
public AdminACL getAdminACL(String adminId) {
  AdminACL policy = adminACLRepository.findByAdminId(Long.parseLong(adminId));
  return policy;
}
}
```

AdminACLRepository

```
package com.myapp.repository;


import com.myapp.model.AdminACL;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface AdminACLRepository extends JpaRepository<AdminACL, Long> {
AdminACL findByAdminId(Long adminId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make use of Spring's `JpaRepository`, you need to add some Spring JPA magic:

```
<beans
    ...
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        ...
        ">

  <jpa:repositories base-package="com.myapp.repository" />
```

In your case, I'd suggest to add it to the `hibernate-context.xml` file.

#### First try

Seems like you did not annotate `com.myapp.repository.AdminACLRepository` (or any implementation thereof) as a `@Component`/`@Service`.

Comment: I already did. Please see below the com.myapp.repository.AdminACLRepository file.

Comment: Me and my browser, we do not find the com.myapp.repository.AdminACLRepository file...

Comment: Changed the hibernate-context.xml (pls check the edited file), but still same error. Also tried including @Component/@Service in com.myapp.repository.AdminACLRepository.

Comment: The @Component/@Service in `com.myapp.repository.AdminACLRepository` is not necessary; I mentioned that before I knew that it is an interface extending `JPARepository`.
Are you sure the stack trace is the same?